# How do I define collisions for x and y separately?

Tags: python, class, object, pygame, collision-detection

So in this function I have collision detection between a ball and a paddle and score (and other stuff that aren't relevant for this question) . When the ball hits the paddle it bounces off in the oposite direction. It works fine for the left side of the paddle, but if the ball hits from the top or the bottom it kinda slides and the score skyrockets.

```
def Objects (paddle,ball,hits,font,black):  
    if ball.BallRect.colliderect(paddle.PaddleRect):
        ball.vx *= -1
        score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits + 1),True, black)
        temp += 1
        
    else:
        score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits),True, black)
        window.blit(score_text,(20,20))
    
    return temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Sometimes the ball doesn't bounce off the paddle in pong game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864205/sometimes-the-ball-doesnt-bounce-off-the-paddle-in-pong-game).

When the ball hits the left paddle, the ball bounces to the right and the following x-direction must be positive. When the ball hits the right paddle, the ball bounces to the left and the following x-direction must be negative.
Use [`abs(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) to compute the absolute value of a number. The new direction of the ball is either `abs(ball.vx)` or `-abs(ball.vx)`.

You have to distinguish between `leftPaddle` and `rightPaddle`

```py
if ball.BallRect.colliderect( leftPaddle.PaddleRect ):
    ball.vx = abs(ball.vx)

    # [...]

elif ball.BallRect.colliderect( rightPaddle.PaddleRect ):
    ball.vx = -abs(ball.vx)

    # [...]
```

Or you need to know which paddle is hit. Pass either `"left"` or `"right"` to the argument `side`:

```py
def Objects(paddle, side, ball, hits, font, black):  
    if ball.BallRect.colliderect(paddle.PaddleRect):
      
        if side == "left":
            ball.vx = abs(ball.vx)
        else:
            ball.vx = -abs(ball.vx)
    
      
        score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits + 1),True, black)
        temp += 1
        
    else:
        score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits),True, black)
        window.blit(score_text,(20,20))
    
    return temp
```

---

If you only have 1 paddle, it is sufficient to set the correct direction. If you have just the right paddle:

```py
def Objects(paddle, ball, hits, font, black):  
    if ball.BallRect.colliderect(paddle.PaddleRect):

        ball.vx = -abs(ball.vx)

        score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits + 1),True, black)
        temp += 1

    else:
        score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits),True, black)
        window.blit(score_text,(20,20))
    
    return temp
```

Comment: Î forgoted to add that there is one paddle. Here's a screenshot https://prnt.sc/we6mcy When the ball hits the top or the bottom of the paddle it slides

Comment: @Tinko So what is the problem? If you have just the right paddle, `ball.vx = -abs(ball.vx)` is the solution. I've extended the answer.

Comment: thanks man. I saw the other post you answered and it works now. By the way, why do I see you on every post on stack overflow?

Comment: @Tinko Thank you. You just see me on the posts with the tag [tag:pygame] (or [tag:opengl], [tag:glsl])

Comment: I posted another question on the same topic. It works fine, but the score skyrockets. It's not visible, but multiple collisions happen at the same time.