# Pygame Paddle Collision with Classes

Tags: python, pygame

So I am currently working on Ping with Pygame and I just can't figure out how I should do the collision with the paddle. I have one Pong Game without Classes where i did it like this

```
if paddle.colliderect(ecl):
    bewegungx = abs(bewegungx)
```

ecl is the ball in this case and here is it with my classes. I currently have only one paddle since I wanna first figure the collision out and then do the rest.

Thank you in advance :)

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Ball():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ball_w = 30
        self.ball_h = 30
        self.ball_x = 100
        self.ball_y = 150

        self.ball_speedx = 3
        self.ball_speedy = 3

        self.ball_draw = pygame.Rect(self.ball_x, self.ball_y, self.ball_w, self.ball_h)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, self.ball_draw)

    def move(self):
        self.ball_x += self.ball_speedx
        self.ball_y += self.ball_speedy
        self.ball_draw.topleft = (self.ball_x, self.ball_y)

    def wall_collision(self):
        if self.ball_draw.top <=0:
            self.ball_speedy = self.ball_speedy *-1
        if self.ball_draw.right >= WIDTH:
            self.ball_speedx = self.ball_speedx *-1
        if self.ball_draw.left <=0:
            self.ball_speedx = self.ball_speedx *-1
        if self.ball_draw.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.ball_speedy = self.ball_speedy *-1




class Paddle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.paddle_w = 30
        self.paddle_h = 130
        self.paddle_x = 10
        self.paddle_y = 150
        self.paddle_speed = 0
        self.paddle_left = pygame.Rect(self.paddle_x, self.paddle_y, self.paddle_w, self.paddle_h)

    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, self.paddle_left)

    def move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_w] and self.paddle_left.top > 0:
            self.paddle_left.y -=7

        if key[pygame.K_s] and self.paddle_left.bottom < 600:
            self.paddle_left.y += 7







ball = Ball()
paddle = Paddle()



while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()

    screen.fill(black)

    #Ball Functionsw
    ball.draw()
    ball.move()
    ball.wall_collision()


    #Paddle Functions
    paddle.draw()
    paddle.move()



    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Ball hits the Paddle, the direction of the Ball changes. Add a method `paddle_left_collision` to the `Ball` class:

```py
class Ball():
    # [...]

    def paddle_left_collision(self, paddle_rect):
        if self.ball_draw.colliderect(paddle_rect):
            self.ball_speedx = abs(self.ball_speedx)
```

Call it in the applicaiton loop

```py
while True:

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()

    # move objects and detect collisisons
    ball.move()
    paddle.move()
    ball.wall_collision()
    ball.paddle_left_collision(paddle.paddle_left)

    # draw scene
    screen.fill(black)
    ball.draw()
    paddle.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(FPS)
```

---

Note that if you have two paddles, change the method as follows:

```py
def paddles_collision(self, paddle_left_rect, paddle_right_rect):
    if self.ball_draw.colliderect(paddle_left_rect):
        self.ball_speedx = abs(self.ball_speedx)
    if self.ball_draw.colliderect(paddle_right_rect):
            self.ball_speedx = -abs(self.ball_speedx)
```

---

See also [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907) and [Sometimes the ball doesn't bounce off the paddle in pong game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864205/sometimes-the-ball-doesnt-bounce-off-the-paddle-in-pong-game)