# I can't get the object to bounce off the walls normally due to its resizing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 650
FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.width = self.image.get_rect().width
        self.height = self.image.get_rect().height
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (400, 600)
        self.changex = 10
        self.changey = -10
    def update(self):
        if self.rect.right >= 800:
            self.changex = -10
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.width*1.2),          int(self.height*1.2)))
            self.width = self.image.get_rect().width
            self.height = self.image.get_rect().height
        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.changex = 10
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.width*1.2), int(self.height*1.2)))
            self.width = self.image.get_rect().width
            self.height = self.image.get_rect().height
        self.rect.x += self.changex
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.changey = 10
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.width*1.2), int(self.height*1.2)))
            self.width = self.image.get_rect().width
            self.height = self.image.get_rect().height
        if self.rect.bottom >= 650:
            self.changey = -10
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.width*1.2), int(self.height*1.2)))
            self.width = self.image.get_rect().width
            self.height = self.image.get_rect().height
        self.rect.y += self.changey

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
ball = Ball()
all_sprites.add(ball)



running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

The problem lies in this place:

```
if self.rect.right >= 800:
            self.changex = -10
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.width*1.2), int(self.height*1.2)))
            self.width = self.image.get_rect().width
            self.height = self.image.get_rect().height
```

Python thinks that `self.rect.right` is the right side of the original size of the object and even when the object has already increased, it continues to bounce off the boundaries with its original size.

In this image, the cube has already gone far beyond the border and pushed off only when it reached its small original right side (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM0ia.jpg)

And this happens only with the right and bottom sides of the object. I don't understand how to make an already enlarged cube bounce off the borders correctly.

Comment: Well, you assign `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` in `__init__`, but then never change `self.rect`, so that is stuck to the original value.

Comment: And how do I change self.rect?

Comment: In a similar way probably as how you update self.width and self.height.

Comment: @9769953 I tried updating `self.rect` this way, but now after every collision with the right wall, the enlarged cube moves to the upper right corner

Answer (score 1):

If your ball is reflected on the wall, you need to adjust the size and position of the ball defined by the `rect` object. Add a method. Add a method that changes the direction of movement and size of the ball when the ball collides with the wall. The position de balles must also be changed. You must make sure that the same collision is not recognized in two subsequent frames, as you would then change the direction of the ball twice.  This is particularly important in this case as you are changing the size of the ball.

```py
def reflect(self, NV, border_rect):
    self.dir = self.dir.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2(NV))
    self.radius = min(50, self.radius + 1)
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.original_image, (self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))
    self.rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)
    self.pos = self.rect.center
```

Note, the important thing is that you shift the ball as soon as it collides with the wall so that it no longer collides with the wall. See also [Sometimes the ball doesn't bounce off the paddle in pong game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864205/sometimes-the-ball-doesnt-bounce-off-the-paddle-in-pong-game).
In the code above, this is achieved with [`pygame.Rect.clamp_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip), which moves the rectangle inside another. In this case it moves the ball rectangle completely inside the border rectangle:

```py
self.rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)
self.pos = self.rect.center
```

Call the method in `update` when the ball collides with the boundary:

```py
def update(self, border_rect):
    self.pos += self.dir * self.velocity
    self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)
    if self.rect.left < border_rect.left:
        self.reflect((1, 0), border_rect)
    if self.rect.right > border_rect.right:
        self.reflect((-1, 0), border_rect)
    if self.rect.top < border_rect.top:
        self.reflect((0, 1), border_rect)
    if self.rect.bottom > border_rect.bottom:
        self.reflect((0, -1), border_rect)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import random

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, startpos, velocity, startdir):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(startpos)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.dir = pygame.math.Vector2(startdir).normalize()
        self.original_image = pygame.Surface((100, 100), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.original_image, (0, 255, 0), (50, 50), 50)
        self.radius = 5
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.original_image, (self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))

    def reflect(self, NV, border_rect):
        self.dir = self.dir.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2(NV))
        self.radius = min(50, self.radius + 1)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.original_image, (self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))
        self.rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)
        self.pos = self.rect.center

    def update(self, border_rect):
        self.pos += self.dir * self.velocity
        self.rect.center = round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)
        if self.rect.left < border_rect.left:
            self.reflect((1, 0), border_rect)
        if self.rect.right > border_rect.right:
            self.reflect((-1, 0), border_rect)
        if self.rect.top < border_rect.top:
            self.reflect((0, 1), border_rect)
        if self.rect.bottom > border_rect.bottom:
            self.reflect((0, -1), border_rect)
   
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_groups = pygame.sprite.Group()
start, velocity, direction = (250, 250), 5, (random.random(), random.random())
ball = Ball(start, velocity, direction)
all_groups.add(ball)

border_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 300, 300)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_groups.update(border_rect)

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), border_rect, 1)
    all_groups.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: When I try to make a stronger increase in the ball when it collides with a wall in your code, it gets stuck in the wall and increases infinitely. Tell me how to do it right please.

Comment: @Kirusha No, that is not true. The code also works if you increase the radius by more than one, e.g. for `self.radius = min(50, self.radius + 5)`. Actually, the only limit is the size of the box.

Comment: But if I use `self.radius = min(50, self.radius + 5)`, then the ball increases only 1 time, and then it does not increase anymore. And if I use `max` instead of `min`, then with large increases in the ball, problems begin.

Comment: @Kirusha No, that's not true. The problem is on your side. My code works correctly. Note that in my code the maximum radius is 50. If you want a larger sphere, you need to increase the maximum radius. e.g.: 100 instead of 50 `self.radius = min(100, self.radius + 1)`

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. I used the code that you originally wrote, but it turns out that you changed it later. Your new code works perfectly, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

here is my method:

```
def update(self):
    if self.rect.right>=WIDTH or self.rect.left<=0:
        #touch vertical edge, reflect x dir
        self.changex*=-1
        self.increase_size()
        # width increases from the right
        if self.rect.right>=WIDTH:
            while self.rect.right>=WIDTH:
                #keep moving left when touching right edge
                self.rect.x-=1
        
    if self.rect.top<=0 or self.rect.bottom>=HEIGHT:
        #touch horizental edge, reflect y dir
        self.changey*=-1
        self.increase_size()
        # height increases from the bottom
        if self.rect.bottom>=HEIGHT:
            #keep moving up when touching bottom edge
            while self.rect.bottom>=HEIGHT:
                self.rect.y-=1
        
    self.rect.x+=self.changex
    self.rect.y += self.changey

def increase_size(self):
        self.width*=2
        self.height*=2
        self.width=min(600,self.width)
        self.height=min(600,self.height)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.width, self.height))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).